Invalid HTTP_HOST on Django (EC2 Aws Ubuntu)
I'm having trouble deploying my Django application. I'm running it using nohup on port 8000 and using nginx with SSL certificate configuration, masking the domain to port 80.
Here are my default Nginx settings:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name fmartns.dev;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fmartns.dev/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fmartns.dev/privkey.pem;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/fmartns.dev;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://3.82.145.23:8000;  # Port where Django is running
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Django's settings.py configuration:
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['fmartns.dev', '*']

SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['http://fmartns.dev']

Error log:
DisallowedHost at /
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'fmartns.dev,fmartns.dev'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this? I've tried various tutorials and configurations both in my settings.py and in the default nginx settings.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about system configuration, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

You are including the headers twice with the include proxy_params and the proxy_set_header.
Since you are already including (include proxy_params) you can safely remove the three proxy_set_header lines in your nginx configuration.

The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.

Thanks for the heads up @TobySpeight, . Though I'm not entirely sure why this question does not fit here? I read the help center as you provided but failed to identify why this wouldn't be a nice fit.
If possible, could you add, or cite the specific rules broken by this question?

I've added a comment to the question - matters of system administration and software configuration are not programming.  There are some good alternative sites where such questions are on-topic, though.
